# Detect install souce in ios app

Tags: ios

I have submit my app to Apple Store successful and I need detect install source because I have more distributors. How can I statistic number of install from these distributors ?

Thank for reading

Comment: just check in you itunes connect then check for sales and trends

Comment: Doesn't your distributors provide you those statistics?

Comment: Use Google Analytics.

Comment: More distributors?  Please expand.

Comment: Thanks for reply all. My distributors provide me all these statistics but I need check it myselft (I pay money back to these distributor for each install successful)

Comment: @EPyLEpSY: GA not support for ios to detect install source. Do you have any other solutions ?

Comment: Sorry i thought you need statistics of total install count. But Google analytics give some advanced statics. If your distributors are in different cities/countries you can check it from location data. Or you can use device's GPS data. Or you can setup simple user management system (login) ETC.